# Найти ошибку в LINQ-запросе

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть БД, в ней есть таблицы:

```
Checkout (Checkout key, ReaderID, BookID LibrarianID, Checkout Date, Return Date)

Authors (AuthorID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)

Books (BookID, Title,  AuthorID, GenreID, ImprintID, Quantity).
```

Наверное уже догадались, что в таблице Books содержится информация о книгах, в таблице Authors инфо об авторах, а в таблице Checkout инфо о выдаче книг.

В своем запросе я хотел получить что-то вроде рейтинга выдачи, какие книги больше всего выдавались и отсортировать полученную таблицу по кол-ву выдач.

```
using (var db = new LibraryContext()) {
            var query = (from che in db.Checkout
                         group che by che.BookID into g
                         from che in g
                         from boo in db.Books where boo.BookID == che.BookID
                         from aut in db.Authors where aut.AuthorID == boo.AuthorID
                         select new {
                             FirstName = aut.FirstName,
                             MiddleName = aut.MiddleName,
                             LastName = aut.LastName,
                             Title = boo.Title,
                             Count = g.Count(),
                         }
                         ).OrderBy(p => p.Count).Distinct().ToList();

            this.dataGridView.DataSource = query;
            this.dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
```

В итоге полученные данные вывести в новую таблицу: ФИО автора, Название книги, Кол-во выдач.

Все получилось, кроме сортировки. Не получается отсортировать в конце по количеству выдач. Помогите :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка видимо в отсутствии join-ов  в запросе.

```
from che in g
from boo in db.Books where boo.BookID == che.BookID
from aut in db.Authors where aut.AuthorID == boo.AuthorID
```

Для примера упростил классы:

```
public class Book
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string authorId { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Checkout
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string bookId { get; set; }
}
```

вспомнил литературу:

```
authors.Add(new Author() { id = "1", name = "Тургенев" });
authors.Add(new Author() { id = "2", name = "Гоголь" });
authors.Add(new Author() { id = "3", name = "Есенин" });

books.Add(new Book() { id = "1", name = "отцы и дети", authorId = "1" });
books.Add(new Book() { id = "2", name = "вий", authorId = "2" });
books.Add(new Book() { id = "3", name = "белая береза", authorId = "3" });

checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "1", bookId = "1" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "2", bookId = "1" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "3", bookId = "1" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "4", bookId = "1" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "5", bookId = "1" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "6", bookId = "1" });

checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "7", bookId = "2" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "8", bookId = "2" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "9", bookId = "2" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "10", bookId = "2" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "71", bookId = "2" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "81", bookId = "2" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "91", bookId = "2" });
checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "101", bookId = "2" });

checkouts.Add(new Checkout() { id = "11", bookId = "3" });
```

переписал:

```
var res = (from c in checkouts
             group c by c.bookId into g
             join b in books on g.Key equals b.id
             join a in authors on b.authorId equals a.id
             select new
             {
                 author = a.name,
                 book = b.name,
                 rating = g.Count()
             })
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.rating)
            .ToList();
```

или на методах расширения:

```
var res = checkouts.GroupBy(g => g.bookId)
            .Select(i => new { bookId = i.Key, cnt = i.Count() })
            .Join(books, g => g.bookId, b => b.id, (g, b) => new { book = b, info = g })
            .Join(authors, g => g.book.authorId, a => a.id, 
                     (g, a) => new { 
                                 bookName = g.book.name, 
                                 authorName = a.name, 
                                 cnt = g.info.cnt })
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.cnt)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

> Не получается отсортировать в конце по количеству выдач.

Distinct должен вызываться до OrderBy.